# Which ORM for node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm

I know this is a common question but i've done tests and i need some particular features!

The features i need are:

- map properties to column names
- use a table name different from the model name
- support for soft-deletes (paranoid mode on sequelize)
- support for record timestamping (with the ability to specify, for every different model, the column name)
- support for foreign keys
- must support mysql and sqlite
- the architecture must support a model per file

Optional features:

- cache (support for redis/memcache)
- command line tool to generate models from database

I've tested:

1. node-orm

   - to handle own column names you need a workaround
   - soft deletes aren't supported and can't be supported even using an external plugin (i tried to wrote one using beforeRemove hook, but i can "stop" it from removing the record)
   - don't support a model per file (you need a workaround)
2. sequelize

   - don't create foreign keys
   - can't map properties to column names
   - support a model per file but it doesn't work very well (you need to put relationship in the file that include the models)
3. node-persist

   - i don't like the need to specify the connection instance for everything

Right now i'm going to test JugglingDB and Bookshelf.js (but i don't like too much the last one).

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything close to Hibernate/Doctrine for Node right now :(

Comment: sequelize looks ok, with some workarounds, remember this is not PHP and things tend to be way too async most of the time, so mix it with async.js and i believe you will get a result.

Comment: @GeoPhoenix the question is not related at all to PHP or Async vs. Sync, the point is that i'm looking for a good ORM :)

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is your site about this question.

Comment: this article should help you : http://www.sitepoint.com/3-javascript-orms-you-might-not-know/

Answer (score 19):

Bookshelf should currently support all of those:

1. The mapping of columns to property names with the
   [format](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-format) and
   [parse](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-parse) methods.
2. Using a different table name with the
   [tableName](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-tableName) attribute.
3. Timestamping can take custom columns with the
   [hasTimestamp](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-hasTimestamps)
   attribute.
4. Foreign keys can be defined with
   [knex](http://knexjs.org) schema builder... they're not well documented but you can
   see an example in the tests [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/test/integration/builder/schema.js#L62)
5. Supports mysql, sqlite and postgres
6. Definitely supports one model per file... the relations are defined in methods, so you can do:

   ```
   var Classroom = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
     tableName: 'classrooms',
     student: function() {
       // Relating to a model from a file in the same directory.
       return this.hasMany(require('./student'));
     }
   });

   new Classroom({id: 1})
     .fetch({withRelated: ['students'])
     .then(function(classroom) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(classroom));
     });
   ```

Official soft delete support is in the works, but is definitely easily achieved by extending the model and providing a new destroy method like so:

```
destroy: function(options) {
   if (options.softDelete) {
     return this.save({'deleted_at': new Date});
   }
   return bookshelf.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this, arguments);
}
```

It doesn't hook into a cache yet, because cache invalidation on relations is pretty tricky, definitely something under consideration.

If you see anything that seems to be missing, feel free to open a ticket.

Comment: The propertie to column name is more a workaround for the missing feature, i don't want to specify extend every single model to handle the parse and format, it, basically, doesn't support FK (if i need to do it on my own using knex, bundled with Bookshelf.js, or with other stuff is a non sense ... defining a relation between two tables should be handled with FK [in most cases]) and, in the end, it is VERY VERY verbose (defining relationship in methods and fetching specifying which related stuff extract isn't good at all)

Comment: Just to note my experience for MySQL, I have used waterline, node-orm2, sequelize, and bookshelf.  Bookshelf was by far the best experience out of them because of it's good documentation, simplistic models, and easy implementation.

Comment: Hi, I've been using Bookshelf a few months now, and am enjoying working with it.. very nice solution you have built there.  I tried to get pagination for my Bookshelf queries using the bookshelf-pagemaker module.  I was able to get basic pagination .. but not seeing how to give the query a WHERE clause.  I was wondering if you have any suggestions on best way to paginate w/Bookshelf.  Thanks , Here's my post about this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/31374653/2162226

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at light-orm: https://github.com/knyga/light-orm
Simple ORM. Don't create foreign keys. Can't map properties to column names. But could be connected to any rdbms, and super simple.