# How to add simple Where-clause with bookshelf-pagemaker

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, bookshelf-pagemaker

Using the **bookshelf-pagemaker** NodeJS Module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-pagemaker
- https://github.com/bhoriuchi/bookshelf-pagemaker

.. I was able to get basic paginate working where it selects all rows from a table. But I am not seeing how to add a WHERE clause to the query.

> QUESTION:
>
> Can someone please share a small example of using bookshelf-pagemaker
>   with search criteria - e.g. *SELECT * FROM user WHERE id > 10* ?

```
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf').mysqlAuth;
var pagemaker = require('bookshelf-pagemaker')(Bookshelf);

var UserDAO = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'user'
});

function getRegisteredUsers(pageNum, pageSize, offset, callback) {   

    var args = {
        params: {
            start: offset,
            page: pageNum,
            length: pageSize
        },
        model: UserDAO
    };

    var resultObj = pagemaker.datatables.paginate(args);
    resultObj.then(function (result) {
        console.log('Enter: paginate(args)');
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: the current version doesn't support this. i will add a "where" param to the args object so that you can specify this and reply with the updated version when i publish it to npm. i did not think of this use case, and may need to rework the module now that i have a better understanding of bookshelf. you may also want to keep an eye out on my dreamcatcher project, as i will be adding a pagination option there and the methodology in that module allows you to do more bookshelf/knex type functions.

Comment: also, the params field of the args object should be the request parameters object from your web service call. i only tested the code with restify so it should be something like req.params from that module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added support for this in the freshly published version 0.1.3. You can now supply a where statement to the args object you pass to the paginate function. the sql statement you supply will be added with an and to the filter sql so you will still be able to use search functionality

your args object would look like

```js
    var args = {
        params: {
            start: offset,
            page: pageNum,
            length: pageSize
        },
        model: UserDAO,
        where: '(id > 10 AND id < 100)'
    };
```

```
var resultObj = pagemaker.datatables.paginate(args);

resultObj.then(function (result) {
        paginateHandler(result);
    });
}

function paginateHandler (result) 
{
    var numPaginatedRecords = result.recordsFiltered;

    var pagesTotal = Math.ceil(numPaginatedRecords / ITEMS_ON_PAGE);

    res.render('my_paginated_view', {
        data: result.data,
        currentPage: <from URL or default 1>,
        pagesCount: pagesTotal
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at my question and updating the module to support the WHERE clause.  Very nice of you to take care of that so quickly.  I hope you don't mind that I edited your post a bit to include some additional code for setting up the correct number of Page links when making a filtered query. Best Regards